# Get-QADUser in a function that returns an array

Tags: powershell, quest

```
function getNTAccounts {
    Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
connect-QADService

    $accounts = @()
   Get-QADUser -CreatedAfter (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) -SerializeValue | Select-Object "samaccountname" | Foreach-Object{ 
        $accounts += $_.samaccountname
   }

   Disconnect-QADService

   return ,$lastaccounts
}




$tmpResult = getNTAccounts
```

Can you please explain to me why I got this:

```
{Quest.ActiveRoles.ArsPowerShellSnapIn.Data.ArsADConnection, Account1 Account2}
```

I'd like to get a simple array but it contains this string in the first element of the array.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these changes:

```
function getNTAccounts {
    Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement
connect-QADService | Out-Null

    $accounts = @()
   Get-QADUser -CreatedAfter (Get-Date).AddDays(-3) -SerializeValue | Select-Object "samaccountname" | Foreach-Object{ 
        $accounts += $_.samaccountname
   }

   Disconnect-QADService

   return ,$accounts
}




$tmpResult = getNTAccounts
```

Piping Connect-QADService to null prevents the extra entry you were getting out. Remember that everything that gets sent to the pipe will be seen as returned from the function. Also you have $lastaccounts instead of $accounts, but I suspect that this was unintentionally done when posting the question.